# What's the difference between takeUnretainedValue and takeRetainedValue?

Tags: swift, memory-management, unsafe-unretained, retained-in-memory

What's the difference between `takeUnretainedValue` and `takeRetainedValue`? Based on Apple's documentation:

> Both of these methods return the original, unwrapped type of the
>   object. You choose which method to use based on whether the API you
>   are invoking returns an unretained or retained object.

But how do I know whether the unmanaged object is an unretained or retained object? For instance, the method `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions:` from `AddressBook` framework returns an unmanaged object `ABAddressBook`, which some tutorials consider this as a retained object. When using `ALAsset`, the method `thumbnail` returns an unmanaged object `CGImage`, which some tutorials consider this as a unretained object.

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how do I know whether the unmanaged object is an unretained or retained object?

It depends on which API you use.

There are some Conventions here: [Ownership Polocy / Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html)

Basically, if a function name contains the word "Create" or "Copy", use `.takeRetainedValue()`. If a function name contains the word "Get", use `.takeUnretainedValue()`.

And, if it does not contains either, as far as I know, we can still use `.takeUnretainedValue()` in almost every cases.

However, every rule has an exception :) for example, see:
[Swift UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFString>?> allocation and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169807/swift-unsafemutablepointerunmanagedcfstring-allocation-and-print/27171498#27171498)

Comment: this is a good, simple, and to-the-point explanation :) Thanks! So, in my case, because `ALAsset` method `someALAsset.defaultRepresentation().fullScreenImage()` returns an unmanaged `CGImage` then I should use `.takeUnretainedValue()`, correct? I mean, `CGImage` doesn't contain "create" or "copy" in its constructor.

Comment: Correct, `fullScreenImage` does not contain "Create" or "Copy". If you are unsure which to use, you might want to find some sample codes in apple.com. For example, [this sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PrintPhoto/Listings/Classes_PrintPhotoViewController_m.html) is using `fullScreenImage`, but not releasing the result with `CGImageRelease`.